# How to preserve text during a postback with ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a Product edit screen. The user can select a Vendor for the Product. To do this, I display a jQueryUI dialog box which allows them to browse for and select a Vendor. When the user selects the Vendor, I update a hidden VendorID input on the page, which is part of my page's model. I also update several divs with details about the Vendor they have selected. These are for display purposes only--only the id is needed to persist the selected Vendor.

This all works fine and dandy except when there is an error on postback, in which case I redisplay the same view. ModelState takes care of preserving all my form fields (including the hidden VendorID). However, my divs with the Vendor text are (of course) empty since they're not posted to the server.

I first went down the path of creating hidden fields for each of my Vendor display fields and putting them on the model. Then the hidden fields survive the postback, but that doesn't solve the problem of actually redisplaying the text on the screen.

The three options I can think of are:

1. On postback, if there is an error, go to the database, fetch the Vendor using the supplied VendorID and re-populate the model with the text I want to display.
2. Use RenderAction and have an action which renders the details of the selected Vendor.
3. Use readonly textboxes instead of divs to display the Vendor details.

None of these feel very satisfactory to me. I feel like I might be missing an obvious solution. Are there any better solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you not have the extra Vendor information come down as part of the main page.  Create a javascript function showVendorInfo().  When called, if the VendorID hidden input has a value, it gets the relevant Vendor information via AJAX and displays it, using an AjaxGetVendorInfo action method.  Call this function from two places:

- In document.ready()
- after a Vendor is selected with jQueryUI display.

Now, this would be in an action method.  You could, if you expect your users to have latency issues, do the following to avoid some ajax calls:  In the view check if you know the VendorID; if so, call Html.RenderAction call the same AjaxGetVendorInfo action method from the view.

A bonus to this is that it avoids what I have found to be a big no-no:  Including both display-only values and model-binding values in your ViewModel.  This makes for a very confusing ViewModel, especially when there are validation errors.  [Getting on soap box]  It's best to have your ViewModel to just have properties intended for modelbinding, for your state.  Put list values, extra display information, etc., into ViewData or have them show up via AJAX.

Comment: It does sound like a clean solution where utilizing the ajax to fetch display data. Slightly related to this solution, if that data comes from the DB, you can use TempData on the server side to cache DB results.  This also avoids an extra trip to the DB.

Comment: @Patrick I like your approach. I tried to use RenderAction like you suggested on page load to avoid an AJAX call, but one problem with that is if there is an error on postback when adding a new Product, the VendorID is not in the Model. Therefore, I can't just call RenderAction using the VendorID on my model without reaching into the ModelState to get it, which seems like a hack to me. Any thoughts on how to best handle this case?

Comment: I'm misunderstanding some part of what you're doing, just not sure where.  You have a VendorID property on the ViewModel, right?  So, user submits the form, and VendorID should be there in the model-bound ViewModel.  In the post action method, before you return the view because of modelstate errors, you're able to ask the ViewModel object for the VendorID, right?  When you return the View when there's validation errors, do pass in the same ViewModel object that you got through modelbinding?

Comment: (cont)  The key is to not think of the ViewModel as being for the Get action method and all the stuff the view needs to originally show up.  The ViewModel exists to maintain the state for the entire life cycle.  VendorID should be on there, even though it's always blank when someone comes to the page fresh.

Comment: If there is an error on add, I create a new instance of the ViewModel. I'm doing this mainly because the ViewModel needs to have its Select Lists repopulated. But it also explains why I don't have the VendorID. The Product wasn't saved, so when I recreate the ViewModel, the VendorID reverts back to the default. I guess this speaks to your suggestion that the ViewModel only have properties for model binding. I'd be interested in hearing more about your reasoning on that. I've been in the camp that everything a view needs should go in a strongly typed ViewModel, but I can be persuaded otherwise.